# How to access homestead on other devices from mac, If running more than one projects in one vagrant box?

Tags: mobile, vagrant, device, homestead

Is there any way to access homestead, running more than one projects. Like if I have setup homestead.yaml file with three different domains, as given below:

```
---
box: laravel/homestead-7
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/Laravelhomestead.pub

keys:
    - ~/Laravelhomestead

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: siteone.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/siteone/public

    - map: sitetwo.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/sitetwo/public

    - map: sitethree.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/sitethree/public

databases:
    - siteone
    - sitetwo
    - sitethree

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

And when I try to access my machine on the same network with my machine allocated IP (192.168.1.6:8000), It works but It goes to sitethree.app, and I want to access siteone.app. If anyone knows how to do that, please leave your answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Linux/Mac (on other machines) you need to add following into your `/etc/hosts` file

```
192.168.1.6 siteone.app sitetwo.app sitethree.app
```

And for MS Windows machines it would be something like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: I have configured my /etc/hosts file like this:

    192.168.10.10   siteone.app
    192.168.10.10   sitetwo.app
    192.168.10.10   sitethree.app

I can access it in my machine, but want to access it from other machines connected on the same network.

Comment: 1) You should do that on all machines in the network. 2) Another option would be to setup a local DNS server in your network (or probably your router already has?)

Comment: I don't have any idea about DNS.